# Make a block level element to have an adjusting width like inline element?

Tags: html, css

By default, block level elements have width of like 100% even without content, it occupies the space across it's parent element horizontally.

Inline elements on the other hand, adjust it's width depending on it's content. If the the content is long, then the element becomes wider, if the content is short the width shrinks.

[image]

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FWXVa/1/).

What I want to achieve here is to make the block-level element to have a width that will adjust depending on it's content like inline element. How will I do that?

Note:

- I want block elements to be block, not inline-block or inline.
- I want
  to avoid floats, I think it can be achieved without floating
  elements.

Comment: LOL Again you changed your question after I answered

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's allowed, if you're against rules, I'm sorry but leave SO for good. You complain too much.

Comment: @NejiHyuga Editing the post is allowed, it's for good. You can delete your answer to avoid downvotes. Besides, I've answered many questions in SO that was edited many times, i never complain. Solving problems is the main goal here in SO if I remember it correctly.

Comment: @dpp I don't complain, the only thing is you add exceptions to your question as you get solutions for it, that's what I am saying

Comment: @dpp Agreed, I didn't forced you to accept my answer, it's just that others don't get what exactly you want.. anyways moderator will delete these comments so no discussions any more on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered that the width of the table is exactly what I'm trying to mimic. It adjust depending on the length of the content. I found a default stylesheet for HTML 4, the table's display property is set to "table" so I tried it to div and it works:

```
div{ display:table; background:yellow; }

<div>lorem ipsum dolor</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbYJ2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can float your block element to left like this

CSS

```
div { background:yellow; float: left;}
```

[**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWXVa/4/)

You can simply break your element later or you can use `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after your floated div...

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWXVa/6/)

Comment: I must admit, your answer gave me an idea.

Comment: I think I found it, `display:table`. I realized that what I'm trying to mimic is the width of the table, I looked for the default style of table and bingo! I also realized I don't like it. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Float the element is not a good practice if you're just wanting to make it act like a block element. All elements around will outline it. Use *overflow: hidden* instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suggest you to add a div or span with `display: inline-block` *INSIDE* your main div with `display: block`. Then use **javascript** to compute the size of inner element. Then set the width of parent element to the same value.

Anyway, your requirements are very strange

Comment: what do you mean? explain the situation, i'm almost sure you're doing something the wrong way.

Comment: I just want to make the div adjust width based on content, that's all :)

Comment: and why don't you just use display: inline-block; ?

Comment: Because it will make it inline, I want it to be like the block which is rendered in new line. It's okay now, found the answer, `display:table`

Answer (score 0):

i 'll give littel sample for you

- HTML

```
lorem ipsum dolor
lorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolor more longger
```

- CSS

  ```
  div { background:yellow; }
  span { background:orange; float:left;display:inline; width:auto;padding:0 3px; border-right:1px solid red;}
  ```

element span is float left, and width depend on the content.